# CentOS - Has AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 but needs AspNetCore.App 5.0.0

Tags: centos7, .net-5

I am trying to run a .NET 5 console application (developed on Windows) in a docker container on CentOS 7.

I have the following:

```
[root@AU4RLBNAGV04A KLM Releases]# dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

But I get this error when I run the container:

```
[root@AU4RLBNAGV04A KLM Releases]# docker logs klmcontainer
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64
```

I tried to install version 5.0.0, but I get this error:

```
[root@AU4RLBNAGV04A KLM Releases]# sudo yum install aspnetcore-runtime-5.0.0
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package aspnetcore-runtime-5.0.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you please include `your_application.csproj` content ?

Comment: Also could you try to install `aspnetcore-runtime-5.0`   with  `sudo yum install aspnetcore-runtime-5.0` and see if the error is still present. that's  the first thing i would try